# Java - Write Code for a Class that isn't yet instantiated?

Tags: java, methods, command, instance

So I'm writing code for a class "Skill" that will be called by another class "Calculator". The Skill class affects the current instance of Calculator by calling its methods.

```
public class Calculator {
    int number = 0;
    ...
    Skill sk = new Skill();
    sk.hitSkill(true);
    ...
    public void setNumber(int newValue) {
        number += newValue;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, the "Skill" class looks like this:

```
public class Skill { 
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    public void hitSkill (boolean someConditions) {
        if (someConditions) {
            calc.setHitNumber(20);
        }
}
```

The above does me no good because "calc" is an instance, but not THE instance of calc I want to be affected.

I have getters and setters for Calculator that Skill would use - but it needs an instance of Calc in order to work. To be precise, it needs *the* Calculator instance that calls it, not just any Calculator instance.

Why don't I just make the Calculator methods static? Because they affect variables that I need to be able to change, which aren't static.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Do you even need two classes?

Comment: Ideally. What I've given of a fairly complex app is a simplified version for the sake of this question. Even so, I could put it all into the one class, but that could be very bloated design which I would rather avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `new Calculator()`, create a constructor for `Skill` that takes a `Calculator` argument.

```
public class Skill {
    private Calculator calc;
    public Skill(Calculator calc) { this.calc = calc; }
}

public class Calculator {
    private Skill sk = new Skill(this);
}
```

Comment: I'd thought of this, but does Java's pass-by-reference state not invalidate this?

Comment: On the contrary, it's pass-by-reference that supports this. That is, a reference to the original object is retained (rather than a copy being made).

Comment: An enlightening tidbit, and one I won't soon forget. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a loop in your composition. You have `Skill` depending on `Calculator` depending on `Skill` ... you'll need to unpick this. You can make this decision based on your understanding of the domain.

One obvious solution is to inject a calculator into `Skill::hitSkill()`, thus:

```
public class Skill { 
    public void hitSkill (boolean someConditions, Calculator calc) {
        if (someConditions) {
            calc.setHitNumber(20);
        }
}

public class Calculator {
    int number = 0;
    ...
    Skill sk = new Skill();
    sk.hitSkill(true, this);   // <== pass in your instance
    ...
    public void setNumber(int newValue) {
       number += newValue;
    }
}
```

If a skill always uses the same calculator, you could inject the `Calculator` at the time of construction (rather than each time `hitSkill()` is called).

Comment: I thought this might be it. I'll give it a try now, fingers crossed.